# Robot framework - Selenium Lib - Getting embedded browser from Outlook

Tags: outlook, robotframework, selenium2library

My solution is using a special way to open a web page: we embedded chrome browser into outlook app.

Now I have to write automation test for it using robotframework.

I tried but selenium cannot detect that browser.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because Selenium uses the Webdriver to start the browser, automating a browser that is not started using webdriver won't be supported.

Alternatives are to use [AutoIT library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/), that automates your keyboard and mouse actions and focuses on windows. [ImageHorizon Library](https://github.com/eficode/robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary#readme) and [Sikuli Library](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary#readme) use image pattern recognition and support both Windows and Linux.

If your target OS is Windows 10, then [Microsoft WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) maybe of interest. This follows a similar approach as AutoIT, but from Microsoft. Does require the Python Appium application to be installed as well.

All approaches have the pro's and con's and in my view beyond the scope of this question.